# How do I automatically close Terminal.app on exit in OS X Lion?

Tags: terminal, osx-lion

I've recently acquired a new Mac with OS X Lion, and I'm tuning it for my needs.

I was trying to configure autoclose on Terminal using its preferences (as I've done with Tiger and Snow Leopard) but it's not working. I've set "Close if the shell exited cleanly" but when I type `exit`, the window gets closed, but the Terminal.app is still open. Its menu is visible, and with <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> I can see it running.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This option has never closed the Terminal application.

Note that the other options are titled *Close the **window*** and *Don't close the **window*** (**emphasis** mine), making it clear that this setting refers to only closing the *window*, not the entire *application*.

---

You could define the following for your shell, e.g. in `~/.bash_profile` for `bash`:

```
function exit {
    osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to quit' 
}
```

Then add `osascript` to the list of applications that don't require confirmation before quitting (in Preferences > Settings > Shell). Type `exit` to exit Terminal, unless there are other tabs with blocking programs running.

You can give it a different name to separate from a regular `exit`, of course. I like `quit` for this.

Comment: Using an AppleScript to quit Terminal is a good idea, but you should probably make it only quit if there are no other windows open: `osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to if not ((count windows) > 1) then quit'`

Comment: @chris Possible, a matter of taste though. I let terminal's exit protection when running processes handle that.

Comment: Daniel Beck, my point is that if you set it up so that any time you exit a shell it runs this, you won't be able to close any terminals unless you want to close them all and quit Terminal. The question asked by Mtorres is how to get Terminal to quit when the last terminal window is closed; to do that, only quit Terminal when there is only one window open.

Comment: @Chris Possibly. We don't know whether the user actually uses multiple Terminal windows. In that regard, your script is technically incomplete, since it ignores possibly existing other tabs; and does nothing (not even close the tab/window) when there are multiple windows. The question makes no mention of tabs either. Without further feedback, we can't know for sure. Also, there's a reason I suggest giving a different name to the function, that way, he actually has a choice.

Comment: Hello both of you! I usually work with multiple tabs, but I don't like to close them all at once. I like your little discussion about it, and I'm staying with Chris suggestion. Anyhow, Daniel pointed right to the solution. Thanks!

Comment: @Chris The user responded to our discussion. Guess you were right after all ;)

Comment: By the way, in case it wasn't clear: I was assuming this script would be automatically run when the shell exits, therefore it would run when *any* terminal is closed and therefore needs to check whether there are any remaining terminals open. If the user invokes it manually, then they may as well just type Command-Q. I also discovered that my script needs to compare against zero rather than one, because in my testing it runs after the window is closed: `osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to if not ((count windows) > 0) then quit'`. But see my next answer for even more details.

Answer (score 1):

To have Terminal quit after you close the last terminal/shell, you can have your shell run an AppleScript when exiting:

```
# Quit Terminal when this shell exists if there are no other terminals open.                                                                                                                    
if [ "$TERM_PROGRAM" == "Apple_Terminal" ]; then
    quit_terminal_when_no_terminals_remain() {
        osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to if running and (count every tab of every window whose tty is not "'"$(tty)"'") is 0 then quit'
    }
    trap quit_terminal_when_no_terminals_remain EXIT
fi
```

The test for Apple_Terminal ensures this code only takes effect when running inside Terminal.

Since this runs asynchronously, the script may run before or after the terminal containing it is closed (though it usually runs after), and if this terminal is closed because the user quit Terminal, Terminal may no longer be running when the script runs, therefore:

1. First it checks whether Terminal is still running. If not, it does nothing.
2. It only quits if there are either no terminals open or only the one for the current tty. It checks whether there are any tabs other than the one for the tty device to which the current shell is connected "$(tty)".

Note that if you invoke any other shell code that traps EXIT, these will interfere with one another. The solution is to create another function that calls the others and "trap the_other_function EXIT" to invoke everything when the shell exits.

By the way, as always, if this functionality is important to you please file an enhancement request with Apple. Ask for a preference setting to make Terminal quit when there are no more windows open: https://bugreport.apple.com/

Answer (score 1):

As a neat solution, try-

open -a /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app  *.py
    OR
open -b com.apple.terminal *.py

For the shell launched, you can go to Preferences > Shell > set it to exit if no error.

This I often use when I need to almost simultaneously run many scripts/commands.

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

A much much easier an elegant solution would be to set an alias in your .bash_profile as this command:

```
alias quit="killall Terminal"
```

Beautiful, uh?

Comment: This will abort, no matter what is running, all of your Terminal sessions. The programs will probably receive `sighup` and terminate in the middle of what they're doing. This only works if you're religiously using `screen` or `tmux`, otherwise the first time you enter it by accident you'll regret it.