# What is the mac terminal command to exit like the "Exit" in ubuntu

Tags: mac, command-line, terminal

I often open my terminal with multiple tabs, and exit with `exit` command in Ubuntu.
What about mac? Except the `Cmd+w`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you have such a command, but I believe you can [set up Mac OS X terminal to close when you type exit](http://www.gontztechnologyservices.com/tips-and-instructions/mac-os-x/setting-up-mac-os-x-terminal-to-close-when-you-type-exit.html).

This will close the window but not the terminal app.
Please have a look at [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/333416/how-do-i-automatically-close-terminal-app-on-exit-inos-x-lion) about how to also quite the terminal app when typing exit.

Comment: So there's no native command like `exit`? Well, I see. Thank you, @OleBrun. :)

Answer (score 2):

I also had this question, but I really don't like the osascript hack. Finally I found [this answer at Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/60196/how-to-have-terminal-close-tab-when-shell-exits/60200#60200). I think it's a native.

[image: screenshot]

The above screenshot shows a Terminal dialog in German, which when translated roughly means:

> the end of the shell
>   conclude if no error occurred.

So it looks like you could configure Terminal to close when the shell is terminated.